# advice on redirecting logged in user in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want it possible that when an authenticated user navigate to the login/register page, his automatically redirect to dashboard...

meaning authenticated user won't be able to visit login/register page.

I know I can use resolve or canactivate to achieve this but want to know if there's a better way and optimise way to accomplish this.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Angular2 has a nice solution for this kind of issues. You can use routegaurd which can take care of what to do with authenticated user and prevent user to navigate to undesired destinations.

[Read more about gaurds](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)
Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it does, only thinking if I can do a work around with root route change state like in angular 1, thanks so much